# Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'ref'; did you mean 'self'? error in swift with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a username in firebase
and this is my code

```
else{
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: SUEmail.text!, password: SUpassword.text!){ (user, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
                self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(Username)

            }
```

in the 5th line I get the following error

> Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'ref'; did you mean 'self'?

I tried doing that but when I do that I get the following error

> Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'child'; did you mean 'children'?

I also tried doing that but when I did I've  got following error

> Cannot call value of non-function type '[UIViewController]'

can you please help me?
Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: When you don't even show how you define a variable that you call 'ref,' one can only take a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need

```
Database.database().reference().child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(Username)
```

OR

```
 var ref: DatabaseReference! // instance var

 ref = Database.database().reference() // in viewDidLoad
```

---

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: SUEmail.text!, password: SUpassword.text!){ (theAuth, error) in

    guard let user = theAuth?.user else { return }

       if error == nil {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signupToHome", sender: self)
                self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(Username)

        }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but now I get the following error: Value of type 'AuthDataResult?' has no member 'uid' Can you please help me thank you in advance

Comment: now I get a Thread that says Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value can you please help me

Comment: in the line with self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(self.Username)

Comment: do you set `ref = Database.database().reference()` in `viewDidLoad` ?? also try to `print(self.Username)` before that line to see whether it's nil or not